# Change TIme Zone in Meteor synced-cron

Tags: meteor, cron

I am using [percolate:synced-cron](https://github.com/thesaucecode/meteor-synced-cron/) in Meteor 1.2
I need to change the timezone 'Asia/Dubai'.
I have tried

```
SyncedCron.config({
    utc: false, (true/false both)
    timezone: 'Asia/Dubai'
});
```

and also in

```
SyncedCron.add({
    name: ....
    timezone: 'Asia/Dubai',
    .........
});
```

But no luck.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:

I have found another fork package where can I use timezone

[saucecode:timezoned-synced-cron](https://github.com/thesaucecode/meteor-synced-cron/)

Comment: You could try 'GST'. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

From the code in the [package](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/blob/master/synced-cron-server.js):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var options = SyncedCron.options;

  log = createLogger('SyncedCron');

  ['info', 'warn', 'error', 'debug'].forEach(function(level) {
    log[level] = _.partial(log, level);
  });

  // Don't allow TTL less than 5 minutes so we don't break synchronization
  var minTTL = 300;

  // Use UTC or localtime for evaluating schedules
  if (options.utc)
    Later.date.UTC();
  else
    Later.date.localTime();

  // collection holding the job history records
  SyncedCron._collection = new Mongo.Collection(options.collectionName);
  SyncedCron._collection._ensureIndex({intendedAt: 1, name: 1}, {unique: true});

  if (options.collectionTTL) {
    if (options.collectionTTL > minTTL)
      SyncedCron._collection._ensureIndex({startedAt: 1 },
        { expireAfterSeconds: options.collectionTTL } );
    else
      log.warn('Not going to use a TTL that is shorter than:' + minTTL);
  }
});
```

You'll notice it either uses utc or defaults to local time.  There is no way to specify a specific timezone.